# Como utilizar dados de outro site via LINK/ID

Tags: php, html

Preciso saber como é possível eu preencher dados em meu site com dados de outro site.

Ex: Meu site tem os campos **('Título, Imagem, Faixas.')** e existe um site com um banco de dados com o mesmo tipo de conteúdo que o meu, então a sacada é, Ex: Vou publicar informações de um disco de um artista, preciso que invés de ter que colocar tudo manualmente dado por dado, eu coloco apenas o link do site com a busca referente ao disco do artista e através desse link meu site iria reconhecer os campos com os dados automaticamente e vincular na minha publicação os dados do outro site referente do link que coloquei.

Preciso apenas saber se tem como fazer isso, e se possível como fazê-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa baixar uma lib inteira como http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ para algo tão simples.

Basta usar o que já tem nativo:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('http://www.google.com/');
$ancoras = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($ancoras as $elementos) {
   echo $elementos->getAttribute('src'), '<hr>';
}
```

Note que alguns sites "exigem" o user-agent, então pode fazer assim:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/';

$headers = array(
    'Accept-language: pt-br',
    'User-Agent: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
);

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => implode(PHP_EOL, $headers)
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, NULL, $context);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($result);
$ancoras = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($ancoras as $elementos) {
   echo $elementos->getAttribute('src'), '<hr>';
}
```

Se tiver bloqueio do `ALLOW_URL_FOPEN` então pode usar curl.

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim, utilizando [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), um exemplo bem simples seria esse:

```
// Recuperando HTML da página com base na URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Buscando todas as imagens
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
```